# How to modify the memtable flush time interval in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have enabled the incremental backup in the cassandra.yaml file. As I know when we enable incremental backups, cassandra will  backup the data (in backups directory) only when the memtable is flushed. But what if the memtable is yet to be flushed? I won't be able to get the incremental backup right?. I know that for the memtable to be flushed there are certain conditions to be met such as time interval or memtable space. My question is how do I modify this so that even if I enter one record after the last snapshot, I can still backup entire data along with that latest entry?
Consider this example

1. Take the snapshot.
2. Clear incremental backup (backups directory)
3. Enter a record to a table.
4. Check for the incremental backup in backups directory. It is still empty.

Now how do I backup the record which is written after the last snapshot?In general how do we backup the entire upto-date data unless we take the snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

You can flush the files manually with `nodetool flush` just before taking the backup. That way you'll always have the latest memtable flushed.

[nodetool docs](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/NodeTool)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to backup a cluster without taking a snapshot you can do it by simply saving everything under /data folder from every node (this includes mainly the .db files stats files etc).

In order to not override files you should store it with the token information as well.

When you want to restore from this backup, you should spin up a cluster with the same number of nodes, and simply copy the data, one-to-one from each backed-up node to a restored node. Pay attention that you'll have to modify cassandra.yaml to include the relevant token in cassandra.yaml (as well as the peers/seeds/etc) for each restored node.

After all the data is copied, you can start C* process on all the nodes.